# Azure DevOps Trigger a "specific stage" in a pipeline based on another pipeline completion

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

My original problem:

I intend to trigger multiple azure devops deployment pipelines in a sequence. is there a way i can achieve this?

To solve problem:

I intend to create simple pipeline, when i invoke this simple pipeline it should trigger all my deployment pipelines  But its not working as

1. my deployment pipelines has several stages (dev ,test & prod etc)
2. I can't enforce sequence to execute my deployment pipelines

First i'm trying to see if i can trigger specific stage (to solve point #1)

I was trying to trigger "selected stage" in my deployment pipeline based on other pipelines.

- I would like to trigger Dev stage in my deployment pipeline when my "DEV CI" pipeline completes
- I would like to trigger Prod stage in my deployment pipeline when my "Prod CI" pipeline completes, It means for prod stage deployment pipeline should execute only prod stage or (dev & prod)

With below test setup, i am able to trigger my deployment pipeline from both CI pipelines, But CI pipelines always triggering complete deployment pipeline not "Stage i wanted".

My deployment pipeline

```
trigger: none
  

pool:
  name: agent

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: devpipeline
    source: dev_ci 
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - master
      stages:
        - dev        
  
  - pipeline: prodpipeline
    source: prod_ci 
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - master
      stages:       
        - prod

stages:
- stage: dev  
  jobs:
  - job: jobtest
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'MY CD PIPELINE DEV stage'

- stage: prod   
  dependsOn:
  - dev
  jobs:
  - job: jobtest
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'MY CD PIPELINE Prod stage'
```

My Prod CI pipeline

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: Agent

stages:
- stage: Prod 
 
  jobs:
  - job: jobtest
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'RUn CI Pipeline Prod stage'
```

My DEV CI pipeline

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: Agent

stages:
- stage: Dev
 
  jobs:
  - job: jobtest
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'RUn CI Pipeline DEV stage'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have tried to repro the same by using the below steps and got the results as expected.**

**Step 1**: Create Sample Dev CI pipeline, Prod CI pipeline and Deployment pipeline as below.

**Dev CI pipeline:**

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
stages:
- stage: Dev

  jobs:
  - job: jobtest
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'RUn CI Pipeline DEV stage'
```

**Prod CI pipeline:**

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Prod 
 
  jobs:
  - job: jobtest
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'RUn CI Pipeline Prod stage'
```

**Deployment pipeline:**

[click here for deployment pipeline code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqUFS.png)

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  pipelines:
   - pipeline: devpipeline
     source: 'CIDevPipeline'
     trigger:
      branches:
         - main
         
   - pipeline: prodpipeline
     source: 'CIProdPipeline'
     trigger:
      branches:
      - main

stages:
- stage: Dev
  condition: or(eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], 'devpipeline'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
  jobs:
    - job: BuildJob
      steps:
      - script: echo Hello world! 

- stage: Prod
  condition: or(eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], 'prodpipeline'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
  jobs:
  - job: Prod
    steps:
    - script: echo Deploying the code!
```

Now run Dev pipeline and check for dev pipeline completion will trigger only the Dev stage in Prod pipeline.
[image]

Now run Prod CI pipeline and check for prod pipeline completion will trigger only the prod stage in Prod pipeline.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping on this @goonababu. I have tested by adding condition and it just works fine.

I am wondering if i can combine dev& prod CI's into one CI pipeline as stages and trigger deployment pipeline respective stages ? in fact that is my target state pipelines should look like. 
However i can't find any variable under resources.pipeline which i can use to filter stages . something like below.
 condition: and(eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], 'cipipeline') , eq(variables['Resources.pipeline.sourcestage'], 'dev')  )